# SVG, text and QGIS compatibility

Tags: qgis, svg

I wanted to test QGIS 3.18 **Parametrizable SVG** functionality. More precisely I wanted to test text replacements (as described by some posters here)

So far I'm trying to make some very very simple .svg using **Inkscape**.

My main issue is that even with these simple SVGs the text is not visible, not well rendered or at least badly positioned. Simple SVGs such as a single letter ou a letter at the center of a circle are always inaccurate.

How can I troubleshoot this behaviour ?

Is there any path to follow to maximize the QGIS compatibility of the generated SVGs?

Is **Inkscape** a tool to avoid?

I really would like to avoid creating SVG files by hand or starting from scratch.